# Laravel multiple checkbox with an input filed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I want to insert multiple checkbox item with an input filed value. If any checkbox is checked then i need to store that checkbox value and this li block slno input filed value. but the problem is both menus and slno array key not matched. So how do i solve that issue.

here is my html code:

```
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="1"> doctor
<input type="number" class="form-control" value="2" name="slno[]">
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="2"> Patients
<input type="number" class="form-control" value="5" name="slno[]">
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox" name="menus[]" value="1"> Manager
<input type="number" class="form-control" value="6" name="slno[]">
</li>
```

my laravel controller code

```
$input = $request->all();
foreach ($request->menus as $key=>$data) {
    $data = new TblMenuAccess();
    $data->user_id = $user->id;
    $data->menu_id = $request->menus[$key];
    $data->quick_menu_sl = $request->slno[$key];
    $data->save();
}
```

Comment: i know but when i check a checkbox then i also need to store that slno value. @TimLewis

Comment: please read my first comment@TimLewis

Comment: but if i didn't checked any or first checkbox then how cross-reference with those. if i check second checkbox it will first index but first checkbox related input filed array index also 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can set id for two inputs inside each li and then do some JavaScript event handler
write onChange for your input (type number) that whenever it changes, in JavaScript function you get its id and value and by the id you have access to input (type checkbox) also and then insert this 2 values in some array:

```
  your_function(your_id) {
              let your_array = [];
              let your_id = [
                  $("input[type=checkbox][id=your_id]:checked").val(),
                  $("input[type=text]").val(),
              ]
              this.your_array.push(your_id)
            }
```

It's just sample code for what you need to do. You should pass your input id to your JavaScript function in onChange and with the id get values of your inputs, insert them to some array and finally insert that array to your final array and work with that